# Socket.Send Differences in .NET Framework 2.0 vs 4.0 for UDP

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a .NET 4.0 application that uses both TCP and UDP to communicate with a server.

The client connects to the server using a TCP connection first, and then they exchange some information via some UDP packets.

The UDP exchange is initiated by the server, which sends a packet to the client. The client receives the packet and responds back to the server, also over UDP.

Sometimes, the server isn't getting the reply. If I recompile the application to target the .NET 2.0 framework, the server always receives the packet.

So to summarize:

- When the client is compiled against the 4.0 framework, the server fails to receive the packet pretty regularly.
- When the client is compiled against the 2.0 framework, the server always receives the packet.
- This behavior is consistent on XP, Vista, and Windows 7.

I know that UDP doesn't guarantee packet delivery, and unfortunately I have no control over this protocol so I can't switch to TCP.

I also know that windows will sometimes drop UDP packets if it needs to refresh the ARP cache, but why does this happen consistently with 4.0 and not 2.0?

I've looked at the 4.0 and 2.0 implementations of the Socket.Send method in Reflector, and they appear identical.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because it is happening somewhere else that I don't have direct access to. All my information is coming via logging. I can't reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: Are you interested in making things "actually" work, or are you just curious why things work "less"?

Comment: I would like to think that knowing why it works less would lead to knowing how to make it actually work.

Comment: What do you mean by "actually work" though? UDP is an unreliable protocol by design, so drops should be expected and handled appropriately by your application. Beyond it being perhaps strange that there are differences between .NET 2 and 4 in the frequency of drops, it would seem that that the protocol is working as expected. I would however suggest that you attempt to reproduce the issue in a minimal test harness to determine whether it's actually the socket implementation in the framework, or perhaps something else in your application that only manifests when using .NET 4.

Comment: "Actually work" was @insipid's term. As I mentioned, I know the limitations of UDP, I just want to know if anyone is aware of differences between .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 that would cause the behavior that I reported.